# Contrib.auth for occasional inquiries?

Tags: django, authentication

I have developed an app for school management. Teachers and others roles have an account (django user) to control student attendance, Behaviors issues, etc.

Student is a model itself. Teacher is a User proxy.

At this moment I'm ready to extend the app to allow parents access to children information (is cruel, but for the sake of students ;)

I'm evaluating this alternatives:

- Make a simple php app only for parent access (with dedicated db user
  and views). It seems secure but I don't like php.
- Add a password field to Student model and build my owner authentication system. I
  don't like to have a 'django authenticated student'.
- Integrating Student authentication with actual auth schema. I don't like this for
  security reason, this means to check all views security, and this mix teachers and students.
- Create a new django application only for students (and parents) with two databases, the 'school' database and a new one with auth for students

What is for you the best way to authenticate parents before to see children information?

Any suggestions are wellcome. Thanks a lot.

Ah! I think that is easy that parents forgot passwords.

School has over 800 students, app store more than 1milion of presence cheks for year, lot of Parents interviews, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django contrib.auth models incorporate groups and permissions in addition to user accounts. In fact regular django users and django admin users share the same model only with different permissions.

Considering, the default authentication model (from a security standpoint) is already shared with much bigger consequences in case of a breach, I don't see a reason why you shouldn't have students authenticate with the same model and just assign them into a separate group and manage their permissions. Your security will not be worse or better from what it already is.

As far as development side goes, all you have to do is simply use decorators on the view handlers which are Teachers/Parents only to limit student access to them.
See: [Permissions decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#the-permission-required-decorator)

If for whatever reason this is unacceptible (although I cannot surmise a reason from what you said), you will have to do either:

1. Write your own middleware that injects itself into contrib.auth (reinvent the wheel)
2. Use an external system to verify permissions (completely orthogonal to Django's approach and will actually complicate your system much more than to use integrated contrib.auth)

Additional down side to doing your own authentication system is that you now have to worry about all kind of security issues that Django solves for you (like CSRF protection, SQL injection/escaping and many others). Not to mention bugs that can creep in vs. using tested and proven code/model provided by contrib.auth.